# Для чего обычно используют XPath? Нужен ли он верстальщику? И если да, то зачем?

Tags: xpath, xslt

Для чего обычно используют XPath? Нужен ли он верстальщику? И если да, то зачем?

Answer (score 1):

Знаете какую роль играет sql в реляционных базах данных? xpath - то же самое, только для xml. [XPath](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath) - почитайте, если и правда интересно. Верстальщику это вовсе ненужно.

Answer (score 1):

По моему щас в css пошла поддержка xpath для доступа к элементам xhtml - поэтому может быть нужно верстальщику. А обычно используют для доступа в xml, xhtml - частный случай

Comment: Да. Вы правы. Есть реализация XPath на javascript. Думаю, в любом случае, почитать стоит.